# Redirect via JS depending on location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

What I try to do is, if a user visits a site with a specific string in the url, he should be redirected randomly to site A or site B.

Here is my Code:

```
  if(window.location.href.indexOf('specialstring1') > -1) {
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
      window.location.href = "/versionA" + document.location.search;
      } else {
      window.location.href = "/versionB" + document.location.search;
    }
  }
  else if(window.location.href.indexOf('specialstring2') > -1) {
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
      window.location.href = "/versionC" + document.location.search;
      } else {
      window.location.href = "/versionD" + document.location.search;
    }
  }
```

The redirect via location.href depending on the string is work perfectly alone. Same with the A/B-switch. Seems, that I make a mistake combining them.

Comment: what's exactly the problem?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115694/why-is-saying-thank-you-in-question-undesirable

Comment: I don't get redirected :(

Comment: did you try to debug to check if you enter in any of the if statments?

Comment: I am stupid - it's working :)